# What will be the numberOfRowsInSection return type for uitableview when XML data is retrieved?

Tags: uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsarray, tbxml

1. I have a `NSMutableArray` named as `records` and a `NSArray`.
2. Now I am retrieving an XML attribute and its value, using `TBXML parser` and inserting the attribute value in the `NSArray`.
3. This `NSArray` is an object of `records`.

What will be the `numerberOfRowsInSection` when I want to display the value of XML data in tableview cell?

This is my data retrieving procedure....

```
[records addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [TBXML textForElement:id],
    [TBXML textForElement:productNumber],
    [TBXML textForElement:name],
    [TBXML textForElement:availableStock],
    [TBXML textForElement:image],
    [TBXML textForElement:quantityOrderMin],
    [TBXML textForElement:dateCreated],
    [TBXML textForElement:dateUpdated],nil]];
```

And my XML data are....

```
<ProductData HASH="21106941">
    <id>1</id>
    <productNumber>a91cc0f4c7</productNumber>
    <name>Product 1</name>
    <seoTitle>product-1</seoTitle>
    <viewCount>0</viewCount>
    <availableStock>100.0</availableStock>
    <lowStock>0.0</lowStock>
    <image>5e928bbae358c93caedf6115fa7d178b.jpg</image>
    <quantityOrderMax>20.0</quantityOrderMax>
    <dateCreated>2011-10-06T16:08:45</dateCreated>
</ProductData>
<ProductData HASH="409555632">
    <id>2</id>
    <productNumber>d8287e2e51</productNumber>
    <name>Product 2</name>
    <seoTitle>product-2</seoTitle>
    <description>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetue...</p>
    </description>
    <viewCount>0</viewCount>
    <availableStock>100.0</availableStock>
    <image>8bbd8dfff3cdd28285d07810a4fe7c32.jpg</image>
    <quantityOrderMin>1.0</quantityOrderMin>
    <dateCreated>2011-10-06T16:08:45</dateCreated>
</ProductData>
```

I am being able to retrieve data in `UITableviewCell`, but it's displaying first two retrieved data of the `NSArray` because the number of rows are two in `records` array. but i want to set the numberOfRowsInsection will be according to the total number of attribute value retrieved by `NSArray`.

I have got the problem and I know the problem is here:

```
  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        NSLog(@"The number of row in the object array:  %d ",[records count]);
        return [records count];
    }
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: please anybody help me as soon as possible.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, Emon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#pragma mark tableview

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    int sectionCount = [records count];
    NSLog(@"section cout: %d",sectionCount);
    return sectionCount;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];
        cell.accessoryView = imageView;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;

        cellView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,8,290, 120)] autorelease];
        cellView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cellView.tag =10;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cellView];

        imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 40, 48, 48)];
        imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"productbox.png"];
        imgView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        imgView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
        imgView.tag = 5;
        [cellView addSubview:imgView];

        CGRect idLabelRect = CGRectMake(65, 0, 190, 18);
        idLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:idLabelRect] autorelease];
        idLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        idLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        idLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        idLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        idLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
        idLabel.tag = 0;

        CGRect statusRect = CGRectMake(65, 22, 190, 22);
        statusLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:statusRect] autorelease];
        statusLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        statusLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        statusLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        statusLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        statusLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
        statusLabel.tag = 1;

        CGRect orderDateRect = CGRectMake(65, 48, 190, 22);
        orderDate = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:orderDateRect] autorelease];
        orderDate.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        orderDate.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        orderDate.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        orderDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        orderDate.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
        orderDate.tag = 2;

        CGRect byRect = CGRectMake(65, 75, 190, 22);
        byLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:byRect] autorelease];
        byLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        byLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        byLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        byLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        byLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
        byLabel.tag = 3;

        CGRect totalRect = CGRectMake(65, 98, 190, 22);
        totalLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:totalRect] autorelease];
        totalLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        totalLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        totalLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        totalLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        totalLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
        totalLabel.tag = 4;

        [cellView addSubview:idLabel];
        [cellView addSubview:statusLabel];
        [cellView addSubview:orderDate];
        [cellView addSubview:byLabel];
        [cellView addSubview:totalLabel];
    }

    cellView = (UIView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
    idLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:0];
    statusLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:1];
    orderDate = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:2];
    byLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:3];
    totalLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:4];
    imgView = (UIImageView *)[cellView viewWithTag:5];
    idLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Order Id: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:0]];
    statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Status: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:1]];
    orderDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:2]];
    byLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"By: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:3]];
    totalLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:4]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //Get the selected country
    NSString *selectedSection = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:0] ];
    dvController = [[OrderDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibNameAndCurrentTweetUser:@"OrderDetailsViewController" bundle:nil:selectedSection];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
    [dvController release];
    dvController = nil;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 130;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 20)];
    [v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    UILabel* hdr = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,0, tableView.bounds.size.width,20)] autorelease];
    hdr.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    hdr.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:12];
    hdr.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    hdr.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [v addSubview:hdr];

    hdr.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Order #%@",[[records objectAtIndex:section] objectAtIndex:0]];
    return v;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 20;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to approach this problem.

1. The right way would be to take a look at [this TBXML tutorial](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/Guides_-_Traversing_Unknown_elements___attributes.html) regarding parsing. This shows you what to do to parse each of the attributes out of each `ProductData` element entry.
2. The brute force method (which isn't one that I would do) would be to parse through your "records" array, which looks like this:

   ```
   @"<id>1</id>",@"<productNumber>a91cc0f4c7</productNumber>",@"<name>Product 1</name>",@"<seoTitle>product-1</seoTitle>",@"<viewCount>0</viewCount>",
   @"<availableStock>100.0</availableStock>",@"<lowStock>0.0</lowStock>",@"<image>5e928bbae358c93caedf6115fa7d178b.jpg</image>",
   @"<basePrice>10.0</basePrice>",@"<costPrice>0.0</costPrice>",@"<height>1.0</height>",@"<width>1.0</width>",@"<depth>1.0</depth>",@"<weight>2.0</weight>"
   ```

   and so on via this fast enumeration

   ```
   for(NSString * elementText in records)
   {
       NSLog( @"%@", elementText );
       // and search for "<" and ">" and strip out the name and the value using
       // substring
   }
   ```

Comment: please check my edited question again.i hope now you will understand the question.

Comment: have you checked my question.if it's not clear to you then tell me then i will brief again.now please help me

Comment: i have got my solution.if i use this... `switch (indexPath.row) {
  case 0:
   cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0]];
   break;`

Comment: now my problem is how may rows will i give at `numberOfRowsInSection` method?