# How can I display all the rows from a database in a tableview

Tags: iphone, database, uitableview

I am using this code to display all the rows from database, but when the tableview loads only the last row shows up.. what am I doing wrong. Please help!!

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSError *error;
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];

if (!mutableFetchResults)
{
    NSLog(@"Cant Fetch");
}

//compare fetched data with user input abd login if match
for(Event *ev in mutableFetchResults)
{
    NSString *cellValue=[ev VidField];
    NSString *cellValue1=[ev ImgField];
    NSLog(@"%@",cellValue);
    NSLog(@"%@",cellValue1);
    [cell.textLabel setText:cellValue];
    cell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:cellValue1];
}
return cell;
```

}

Comment: Have written this loop in any method. Paste the code of delegate methods as well for better understanding.

Comment: hey thanks for reply I have written this in cellForRowAtIndexPathmethod

Comment: i have edited and pasted entire function. Thanks

Comment: Create a different function which will fetch ur data in an array. Set row equal array count. Then Event *ev = (Event*)[myFetchResults objectAtindexPath:indexPath.row];
  cell.textLabel.Text = [ev VidField];
  cell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[ev ImgField]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do like this;

in .h file;

```
NSMutableArray *myFetchResults;
```

in .m file;

```
-(void)getAllDataFromDatabase{ // call it to get data
   myFetchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   //database connection codes
   myFetchResults = mutableFetchResults; // now you have an array with all objects.
}

in UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method:
{
  Event *ev = (Event*)[myFetchResults objectAtindex:indexPath.row];
  cell.textLabel.Text = [ev VidField];
  cell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[ev ImgField]];
}
```

i think this will work.

Comment: NSMutableArray' may not respond to '-objectAtindexPath:'

Comment: Event *ev = (Event*)[myFetchResults objectAtindexPath:indexPath.row]; in this line its giving a warning
 NSMutableArray' may not respond to '-objectAtindexPath:'

Comment: ohh sry it was my fault, you should use -objectAtIndex method.

Comment: I did it but still the same warning. Err sry.. its now showing only the first row.. and i checked in the database all the rows were present.

Comment: its now showing only the first row.. and i checked in the database all the rows were present.

Comment: ok.. so i guesss its my fault in implementing.. i am calling the getAlldatafromdatabase in viewdidload.. where should i call it?

Comment: you can call it before calling `[tableView reloadData];`

Comment: Worked!!!
Thanks a ton.
I made a stupid mistake even after implmenting your core. I was returning 1 in the following function  :P
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [myFetchResults count];
}
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This code repeatedly sets different values to the same `cell` instance, so it will end up set to whatever the last event in your fetch results is. Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method should be using the `indexPath.row` to set the values for a cell from the specific event at that point in your `mutableFetchResults` - if this is an array, it would be something like:

```
Event *ev = [mutableFetchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *cellValue=[ev VidField];         
NSString *cellValue1=[ev ImgField];         
NSLog(@"%@",cellValue);         
NSLog(@"%@",cellValue1);         
[cell.textLabel setText:cellValue];         
cell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:cellValue1];
return cell;
```

It is hard to give any more details without seeing more code, but this should set you on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

You're just overwriting the value in `cell.textLabel`. If your `for` loop were unfurled it would look something like this:

```
cell.textLabel = row1Text
cell.textLabel = row2Text
...
cell.textLabel = rowNText
```

You should set your cell text in `– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` using the `indexPath.row`  to select which record you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should use if(Condition) for it. Because, for() iterate until last record will be get and set record's data.

Answer (score 0):

i think at first take your `mutableFetchResults` in `viewdidload` then retain the `[mutableFetchResults retain]`.

then number of rows of table will be `[mutableFetchResults count]`

then in make this code...

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
 cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


}
NSString *cellValue=[indexpath.row VidField];
NSString *cellValue1=[indexpath.row ImgField];
NSLog(@"%@",cellValue);
NSLog(@"%@",cellValue1);
[cell.textLabel setText:cellValue];
cell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:cellValue1];
return cell;
}
```

if any code you do not understand then tell me...because i faced same problem...if you want to see more the see my solution....[What will be the numberOfRowsInSection return type for uitableview when XML data is retrieved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806803/what-will-be-the-numberofrowsinsection-return-type-for-uitableview-when-xml-data/8076462#8076462)